# get a python docker container to interact with a redis docker container

Tags: python, docker, redis, containers

I'm new to docker, redis and any kind of networking, (I know python at least!). Firstly I have figured out how to get a redis docker image and run it in a docker container:

```
docker run --name some-redis -d redis
```

As I understand this redis instance has port 6379 available to connect to other containers.

```
docker network inspect bridge

   "Containers": {
        "2ecceba2756abf20d5396078fd9b2ecf0d60ab04ca6b8df5e1b631b6fb5e9a85": {
            "Name": "some-redis",
            "EndpointID": "09f0069dae3632a2456cb4d82ad5e7c9782a2b58cb7a4ee655f57b5c410c3e87",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
```

If I run the following command I can interact with the redis instance and generate key:value pairs:

```
docker run -it --link some-redis:redis --rm redis redis-cli -h redis -p 6379
set 'a' 'abc'
>OK
get 'a'
>"abc"
quit
```

I have figured out how to make and run a docker container with the redis library installed that will run a python script as follows:

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ADD redis_test_script.py /
RUN pip install redis 
CMD [ "python", "./redis_test_script.py" ]
```

Here is redis_test_script.py:

```
import redis
print("hello redis-py")
```

Build the docker image:

```
docker build -t python-redis-py .
```

If I run the following command the script runs in its container:

```
docker run -it --rm --name pyRed python-redis-py
```

and returns the expected:

```
>hello redis-py
```

It seems like both containers are working ok, the problem is connecting them both together, I would like to ultimately use python to perform operation on the redis container. If I modify the script as follows and rebuild the image for the python container it fails:

```
import redis
print("hello redis-py")
r = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0)
r.set('z', 'xyz')
r.get('z')
```

I get several errors:

```
...
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
...
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.
.....
```

It looks like they're not connecting, I tried again using the bridge IP in the python script:

```
r = redis.Redis(host="172.17.0.0/16", port=6379, db=0)
```

and get this error:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to 172.17.0.0/16:6379. Name or service not known.
```

and I tried the redis sub IP:

```
r = redis.Redis(host="172.17.0.2/16", port=6379, db=0)
```

and I get this error:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to 172.17.0.2/16:6379. Name or service not known.
```

It feels like I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about how to get the containers to talk to each other. I've read quite a lot of documentation and tutorials but as I say have no networking experience and have not previously used docker so any helpful explanations and/or solutions would be really great.

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's all about Docker networking. Fast solution - use `host` network mode for both containers. Drawback is low isolation, but you will get it working fast:

```
docker run -d --network=host redis ...
docker run --network=host python-redis-py ...
```

Then to connect from `python` to `redis` just use `localhost` as a hostname.

Better solution is to use docker user-defined bridge network

```
# create network
docker network create foo
docker run -d --network=foo --name my-db redis ...
docker run    --network=foo python-redis-py ...
```

Note that in this case you **cannot** use `localhost` but instead use `my-db` as a hostname. That's why I've used `--name my-db` parameter when starting first container. In user-defined bridge networks containers reach each other by theirs names.

Comment: Awesome - I've got both methods to work! - Thanks so much, I spend most of this afternoon on that!!

Answer (score 4):

**Do:**

- Explicitly create a Docker network for your application, and run your containers connected to that network.  (If you use Docker Compose, this happens for you automatically and you don’t need to do anything.)

  ```sh
  docker network create foo
  docker run -d --net foo --name some-redis redis
  docker run -it --rm --net foo --name pyRed python-redis-py
  ```
- Use containers’ `--name` as DNS hostnames: you connect to `some-redis:6379` to reach the container.  (In Docker Compose the name of the service block works too.)
- Make the locations of external services configurable, most likely using an environment variable.  In your Python code you can connect to

  ```py
  redis.Redis(host=os.environ.get("REDIS_HOST", "localhost"),
              port=int(os.environ.get("REDIS_PORT", "6379"))
  ```

  ```sh
  docker run --rm -it \
    --name py-red \
    --net foo \
    -e REDIS_HOST=some-redis \
    python-redis-py
  ```

**Don’t:**

- `docker inspect` anything to find the container-private IP addresses.  Between containers you can always use hostnames as described above.  The container-private IP addresses are unreachable from other hosts, and may even be unreachable from the same hosts on some platforms.
- Use `localhost` in Docker for anything, expect the specific case of connecting from a browser or other process running *directly* on the host (not in a container) to a port you’ve published with `docker run -p` on the same host.  (It generally means “this container”.)
- Hard-code host names in your code like this; it makes it hard to run the service in a different environment.  (For databases in particular it’s not uncommon to run them outside of Docker or even in a hosted cloud service.)
- Use `--link`, it’s outdated and unnecessary.

Comment: Very helpful to have some guidance on this. On the subject of best practices; is it better to make 2 separate containers, such as 1 for python and 1 for redis, OR is it better to use the .yml file to group several images together? Or is it simply a preference? How could this example be launched using a .yml? I'm happy to post this as a separate question if you prefer? Many thanks

Comment: Two separate containers is almost always right (especially because you can use the canned `redis` image unmodified).  Putting them in a single `docker-compose.yml` is very routine, if you’re using that tool.  The Docker documentation includes a [Django and PostgreSQL example](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) that you could adapt.