# Connection between python and Redis

Tags: python, docker

i'm trying to implement via python a mini database with Redis, open in the background via Docker.
After opening port 6666: 6379 (working), I wrote some python code that should connect to redis to get the qweries written. however this does not happen. Can anyone help me fix the code?
The error that the system gives me is that it cannot connect to Redis.
Many thanks in advance

```
mport redis

close_everytime = False

choice = None
redis = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379, db=0, charset='utf-8', decode_responses=True)

if not redis.ping():
    raise "connection error"

if not redis.exists("nextp"):
    redis.set("nextp", 0)

while True:
    print("1 - proposed creation")
    print("2 - vote proposal")
    print("3 - outcome")
    print("4 - Reset")
    print("5 - exit")
    try:
        choice = int(input("> "))
    except ValueError:
        pass

    if choice == 1:
        key = "pr:"+redis.get("nextp")
        redis.incr("nextp")

        proposer = input("proposer: ")
        redis.hset(key, "proposer", proposer)

        title = input("title: ")
        redis.hset(key, "title", title)

        description = input("description: ")
        redis.hset(key, "description", description)

        redis.zadd("rank", {key: 0})
    elif scelta == 2:
        userid = int(input("isert your user id: "))
        proposal = input("Insert proposal to vote")
        if not redis.exists("pr:"+proposal):
            raise "error, lthis proposal doesn't exists"

        print(redis.smembers("voters:pr:"+proposal))
        print(f"'{idutente}'")
        if redis.sismember("voters:pr:"+proposal, userid):
            raise "The user already voted"

        redis.sadd("voters:pr:"+proposal, userid)
        redis.zincrby("rank", 1, "pr:"+proposal)
    elif choice == 3:
        rank = redis.zrange("rank", 0, -1, desc=True, withscores=True)
        # print(rank)

        point_first = int(rank[0][1])
        print("this is the winner rank: ", point_first, "point")
        for i in range(len(classifica)):
            if rank[i][1] == point_first:
                print(rank[i][0], "from title:", redis.hget("pr:"+str(i), "title"))
    elif choice == 4:
        redis.flushall()
    elif choice == 5:
        break
    else:
        print("error, tap 5 to esc")

    if close_everytime:
        break
```

On cmd connecting to docker i type:

```
docker run --network biscotto --rm --name stefano -d redis
docker run -it --network biscotto -p 6666:6379 --rm redis redis-cli -h stefano
```

i would expect a connection from python to redis, but this one fails with this error

```
Unable to establish connection. Persistent rejection of the target computer.
```

Comment: Is the program running in a container (in which case `localhost` refers to its own container; also see [get a python docker container to interact with a redis docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150125/get-a-python-docker-container-to-interact-with-a-redis-docker-container), and use the `docker run --name` name `stefano` as a host name) or on the host (there are two errors here)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a minimal reproducible example, thanks!

Comment: I will edit the post with a runnable code!

Comment: i edited the file, now it should be error free python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution give the redis container a name with `--name redis`

`docker run -it --network biscotto --name redis -p 6666:6379 --rm redis redis-cli -h stefano`
`

Change host in redis to the redis container name

`redis = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379, db=0, charset='utf-8', decode_responses=True)`

Comment: thank you very much, now I try to implement the program with this string of code and I hope everything goes well! thank you again